# Programmatically change Chrome extension update frequency

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome App (as a packaged app/extension) which purpose is to act as the base platform for several fullscreen apps to be build on top of. Chrome will be running on Ubuntu Linux.

And no trouble so far. But then I was told, that an intended app it is to be the platform for requires the source code to be updated with very short notice, as it probably is to be deployed for large scale use *before* the system has been tested through (even though it's a bad idea to deploy software that's not completely stable, but we're on a tight schedule). The problem is, that the "a few hours" interval for the autoupdating mechanism just isn't good enough.

So I somehow need to have the updating interval changed. I know this can be done with the `--extensions-update-frequency` command line switch, but as apps cannot access the command line (for obvious security reasons), and I'd prefer that the intended background page was to handle all the "administration", I don't think that switch is possible to use.

Is it somehow possible to update at a higher frequency? Or at times when it's ordered to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now a method [`chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-requestUpdateCheck):

> Requests an update check for this app/extension.

It will return a status, which can be either "no_update", "update_available" or "throttled".

Unfortunately, the docs do not specify the limits for frequency that will trigger "throttled".

Comment: I would argue that this is the better answer. While it doesn't answer the specific question as it's worded, it is probably the answer that was sought for.

Comment: I can confirm that when called, if there is an update, the extension is immediately updated and restarted. Otherwise it throttles which, as of writing, lasts about an hour.

Comment: I'm sorry for not seeing this sooner. Indeed, it does answer my question exactly as it was meant (sorry if I was unclear, I always seems to make a word salad of things) - I've now chosen this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your best option will be to have the extension manually check with your servers for an updated version. If there is an updated version show the user a [desktop notification](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html) to manually update.

---

Potentially you could write a [NPAPI plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) to modify the update frequency.

---

This may cause issues with [CSP](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/manifest.html#content_security_policy) but you can try to live load JavaScript from your server that executes in the extension. In this case to "update" your extension you would simply update the JS hosted on your servers and the extension would automatically start using it on next load.

Comment: Ew, dammit.. You're sure this is the only way? Because user interaction, other than visual, is not an option... But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I've added an additional two options. I'm not certain about their viability but they are options to explore.

Comment: You're fantastic, thank you! I've also considered using NPAPI, but how would it be able to force an update? Do you mean by killing off Chrome and launch it again with the `--extensions-update-frequency` parameter or what?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly but in theory somewhere in Chrome is a setting where you can change the update frequency without launching it with the flag. You would likely have to dig through the source or ask on the chromium dev list.